# White boxes in markdown view

Tags: bug, design, markdown

On sites where the background is not white, you can see white spaces when looking at anything in side-by-side markdown mode, [including suggested tag wiki edits](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/329853), where it is very noticeable and awkward-looking:

> [image: white rectangles bug]

It's also visible in the [revision history of posts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/143993/revisions), where it's a border. In fact, it's `border-X-color` being white that's causing this.

Comment: The boxes blend perfectly into the background on the most sites. It just looks weird on the sites with pink backgrounds (ELU, RPG, etc)

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard Nicely summarized.

Comment: I don't see anything weird. Even the FRC aren't helping. There are no white boxes there. Everything looks like a uniform color. Is that a sign my screen is not correctly adjusted?